# jQuery UI Stars Plugin is not loaded inside a .load callback

Tags: jquery, asp.net, plugins, rating

I am new to jQuery and cannot determine why this plugin does not exist within the context of the callback. I have an asp.net page with a master page.

Here is code in the head of the master:

```
<!-- jquery ui css -->
<link href="/css/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="/css/master.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>    

<!-- jquery -->
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- jquery ui -->
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>  
<!-- custom menu code -->
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/js/fg.menu.js"></script>   
<!-- stars -->
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/js/jquery.ui.stars.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/js/master.js"></script> 

<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="outerHead" runat="server" />
```

Then, within the default.aspx page, I have some nested callbacks using `jQuery.load()` as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

            if (jQuery().stars) {
                alert('LOADED');// IS LOADED HERE
            } else {
                alert('NOT LOADED');
            }

            // load top products
            $("#topProducts").html(ajaxLoaderBar).load("/topproducts.aspx?count=3 #main", function () {

                if (jQuery().stars) {
                    alert('LOADED'); // IS LOADED HERE
                } else {
                    alert('NOT LOADED');
                }

                // setup rating history
                $(".showRatingHistory", $("#topProducts")[0]).click(function () {

                    if (jQuery().stars) {
                        alert('LOADED');
                    } else {
                        alert('NOT LOADED'); // IS NOT LOADED HERE
                    }

                    $(this).hide();
                    var vendor = $(this).parents(".rpt-container").find("#vendorName").html();
                    $(this).next().html(ajaxLoaderBar).load("/ratinghistory.aspx?showThumbnails=false&vendor=" + vendor + " #main", function () {
                        $('.editRatingLink').click(function () {
                            if (jQuery().stars) {
                                alert('LOADED');
                            } else {
                                alert('NOT LOADED');  // IS NOT LOADED HERE
                            }

                            // load dialog

                        });
                    }).css("overflow-y", "scroll").css("border", "1px solid #eee");
                });

                // Create stars from :radio boxes
                $(".stars", $("#topProducts")[0]).stars({
                    cancelShow: false,
                    split: 2,
                    callback: function (ui, type, value) {
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

The comments show where the page is indicating that jQuery().stars is defined. I do not understand how to determine the scope of the 'stars' plugin I am trying to use (http://orkans-tmp.22web.net/star_rating/), and why it seems to work within the callback of the outer load but not the inner. Help!

****EDITED****

So I developed a way to make this work. I am unclear on why the jquery stars ui plugin does not seem to exist inside the inner .load callbacks, but I was able to resolve the problem by injecting the following code to force the plugin to be loaded:

Replace

```
    if (jQuery().stars) {
        alert('LOADED');
    } else {
        alert('NOT LOADED'); // IS NOT LOADED HERE
    }
```

In my question with:

```
    // ensure the stars plugin is available
    if (!jQuery().stars) {
        $.getScript('/js/jquery.ui.stars.js')
    };
```

This way, if the plugin is not available, it will load it within the current .load callback context. Works for me, but I still don't understand how the scope of the plugin is determined. Thanks!

***EDITED***
I modified the original code to show that I am load loading only the #main div in the child pages

****EDITED AGAIN****

Ok, this is driving me nuts... I have distilled it down after 24 hours...

Can some jQuery guru explain to me why:

```
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            // load top products
            $("#topProducts").html(ajaxLoaderBar).load("/topproducts.aspx?count=3 #main", function () {

                // EXISTS HERE
                console.log(jQuery().stars);  // Firebug displays: function()            

                $(".showRatingHistory", $("#topProducts")[0]).on("click", function (event) {

                    // DOES NOT EXISTS
                    console.log(jQuery().stars); // Firebug display: undefined
```

This has something to do with the scope of the jquery ui widget plugin I am trying to use but I can't quite understand it...

Comment: More than likely the page you are loading is pulling in a new copy of jquery which is overriding the one on the parent page. Try pulling only specific content from the page you are loading, such as all html within a div with a given id. `$("#someid").load("somepage.aspx?foo=bar #idofdivtopull",...);`

Comment: Thanks Kevin, that was one thing I was unsure of... does the page I am loading need to be a full page and have a head, body, etc... I am going to try as you suggest.

Comment: Ok, I tried and I am now only loading a container div within each of the load calls i.e. $("#topProducts").html(ajaxLoaderBar).load("/topproducts.aspx?count=3 #main", function () { yet still no luck...

Comment: Can you update the code in your question to what you are using now? The page you are loading does not need to be a full page, however, it can be.